# How to change this regular expression to be case insenstive (looking for src tag)

Tags: java, regex

```
Regualar expression: <img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>
```

This works fine when 'src' is in lowercase and manages both single and double quotes.
I would like this expression to return matches for following test data

```
1. <html><img src ="kk.gif" alt="text"/></html>
2. <html><img Src ="kk.gif" alt="text"/></html>
3. <html><img sRC ="kk.gif" alt="text"/></html> (any charcter in 'src' can be uppercase/lowercase)
4. <html><img SRC ="kk.gif" alt="text"/></html>
5. <html><img src ='kk.gif' alt="text"/></html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the pattern with the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag. See [`Pattern.compile(String, int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String,+int)). This will affect the entire string, which means the `img` also.

Or the cheap way, change `src` to `[Ss][Rr][Cc]`. This will just affect the `src` portion.

Comment: Thanks; just curious; do you mean efficient/faster when you say "cheap way" here?

Comment: I meant it was the lowest-effort way.

Comment: Compile it once and reuse. more efficient/faster. :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that if you want to process HTML, the best way to go is to use a real HTML parser.

Although I am not familiar with Java, there seems to be quite a few to choose from: [Open Source HTML Parsers in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers).

This will allow you to deal with cases like an other attribute being before the src and including the character '>', which is valid HTML, or the src attribute including a quote, and probably a few other unlikely but possible trickeries.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the expression to case insesitve using "(?i)"

```
Regular expression: (?i)<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>
```

for just a part of the expression, use "(?i:part)"

```
Regular expression: <img[^>]+(?i:src)\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>
```

or just do it using the second argument of Pattern.compile

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

[]]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Case.html)

You have to set case insensitivity in the pattern constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:
You might replace the `src` with `[S|s][R|r][C|c]` if you only want
case insensitivity applied to `src`.

KT