# How can I change Regex search in java to overlook case

Tags: java, regex

How can I change the following code so it will not care about case?

```
public static String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag)
            throws DataNotFoundException {
        String value = null;
        Matcher m = null;

        int count = 0;
        try {

        String searchFor = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)</" + tag + ">";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor);

         m = pattern.matcher(inHTML);


            while (m.find()) {
                count++;


                return inHTML.substring(m.start(), m.end());
                // System.out.println(inHTML.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Can't Find " + tag + "Tag.");
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException("Can't Find " + tag + "Tag.");

        }

        return inHTML.substring(m.start(), m.end());

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102077/how-to-change-this-regular-expression-to-be-case-insenstive-looking-for-src-tag

Answer (score 6):

Give the [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag to [`Pattern.compile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)):

```
String searchFor = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)</" + tag + ">";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
m = pattern.matcher(inHTML);
```

(Oh, and consider [parsing XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [instead of using a regular expression to match a nonregular language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).)

Comment: It won’t matter for this ASCII‐only example, but if you don’t add `UNICODE_CASE`, then you will mess up on things like Greek sigmas, since there are two lowercase versions and one uppercase version, and a case‐insensitive match of any one of them is required to match any and all three of them.

Answer (score 1):

First, read [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

To answer your question though, in general, you can just put `(?i)` at the beginning of the regular expression:

```
String searchFor = "(?i)" + "<" + tag + ">(.*?)</" + tag + ">";
```

The [Pattern Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) explains

> Case-insensitive matching can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?i)`.

Since you're using `Pattern.compile` you can also just pass the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag:

```
String searchFor = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)</" + tag + ">";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

You should know what case-insensitive means in Java regular expressions.

> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in conjunction with this flag.

It looks like you're matching tags, so you only want US-ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for catching the `UNICODE_CASE` flag; please always forget this.  In hindsight it would perhaps have been better if the flags had been respectively named `ASCII_CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `UNICODE_SIMPLE_CASE_INSENSITIVE`, thereby leaving open the door for an eventually `UNICODE_FULL_CASE_INSENSITIVE` for when the engine is upgrade to do full casefolding instead of the merely simple casefolding it does now. (Note that Java’s `String` methods *do* do full casemapping, unlike its `Character` methods which do only simple casemapping.)

Comment: @tchrist, Would the difference between full and simple be things like Turkish i's that are in the supplemental (I forget the terminology from the unicode spec) case mappings?

Comment: No, that’s locale-specific casing.  Full casing is when you can get back an output string that differs in length (by code point count) from that of the input.

Comment: @tchrist, Understood.  For example, ÆON vs Aeon where the first uses an ae ligature.

Comment: Actually, the casefold of `Æ`  is just `æ` (one code point), although the casefold of `ﬃ` is `ffi` (three code points).

Answer (score 1):

You can also compile the pattern with the case-insensitive flag:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```